# Slice index out of range but one space is free

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to figure out how slice resizing works and I have the following sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    s := []byte{'A', 'W', 'T', 'Q', 'X'}
    b := s[2:4]
    fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))
    fmt.Println(string(b), len(b), cap(b))
    b[1] = 'H'
    b[2] = 'V'
    fmt.Println(string(b))

}
```

The compiler complains:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

`b` has capacity of `3`, why can I not assign like

```
b[2] = 'V'
```

Comment: And btw it's not the compiler that complains: it's the runtime (`panic: runtime error: ...`).

Comment: Really helpful on all these types of issues is taking the whole Go Tour tour.golang.org and reading the blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is only valid in the range of `0..len(b)-1`. Quoting from the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types):

> The elements can be addressed by integer indices `0` through `len(s)-1`.

Elements beyond the length (but within the capacity) are unavailable through indexing. You can only access those elements if you [reslice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the slice to include those elements (but within the capacity).